# $valid inside ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to show errors in angular js in case the all form input are invalid. I also know how to show message if one field is invalid.

The Question is how to show a message inside ng-repeat of items, when only some of the items are invalid.

```
<form name=form>  
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <textarea ng-model="item.value" name="item">
    <div ng-show="form.name.$invalid">
              I want to show this message if this   textarea is invalid
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-show="form.$invalid">You have error in your form</div>
</form>
```

Please see this above line `<div ng-show="form.name.$invalid">` it will show the message `x` times, but I want to show the invalid message only for the invalid input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap everything under the `ng-repeat` with a `<div>` that has [`ng-form`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

> ### ngForm
>
> Nestable alias of form directive. HTML does not allow nesting of form elements. It is useful to nest forms, *for example if the validity of a sub-group of controls needs to be determined*.
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm